# Problems using the dsc_xaduser resource in Puppet

Tags: powershell, puppet, dsc

I have been scratching my head for a while trying to understand how to correctly craft a dsc_xaduser resource in a Puppet Manifest. If you have ever used this resource (or understand DSC good enough to give a shot to my question) I will be deeply grateful.

Here is the thing: I'm trying to create a new Active Directory user using this resource declaration

```
dsc_xaduser { 'SQLServerServiceAccount':
  dsc_ensure                        => 'present',
  dsc_domainname                    => 'MY-DOMAIN',
  dsc_username                      => 'SQLServerServiceAccount',
  dsc_password                      => {
    'user'     => 'SQLServerServiceAccount',
    'password' => 'letmein'
  },
  dsc_passwordneverexpires          => false,
  dsc_domaincontroller              => 'MY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYSERVER',
  dsc_domainadministratorcredential => {
    'user'     => 'DMTDEVOPS\\Administrator',
    'password' => 'my-password'
  },
}
```

It doesen't look very fancy... just a single AD user and that's all.

Now, when I try to run this manifest, the error I get is:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Dsc_xaduser[SQLServerServiceAccount]: Could not evaluate: Exception calling ".ctor" with "4" argument(s): "The server could not be contacted."
```

I'm pretty sure that MY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYSERVER exists. I can totally ping it from the server I'm running the manifest. I can also open a PowerShell session and issue a Get-AdUser cmdlet and do things like that. But something is wrong in my resource and I can't figure what!

If you get any idea what could be wrong, I would totally appreciate some help here

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got this working? I would suggest giving the FQDN a go in `dsc_domaincontroller => 'MY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYSERVER.DOMAIN.COM`